# Do you need to understand measure theory to learn Lebesgue integration?

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question, lebesgue-integral

I want to learn the topic of Lebesgue integration but I know no measure theory yet. Would I be correct in assuming that I first need to learn measure theory (or at least get a feel for it) before tackling the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Yes, the [Daniell-Riesz approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniell_integral) is an alternative development which avoids measure theory for the most part and results in an integral that is equivalent to Lebesgue's, at least for functions of a real variable.. See for example [The Lebesgue Integral for Undergraduates](https://www.amazon.com/Lebesgue-Integral-Undergraduates-Maa-Textbooks/dp/1939512077)

Comment: Much of the difficulties in measure theory come from the fact that there exist non-measurable sets. If you are interested in only the Lebesgue integral itself, you can pretty much assume that every sets are measurable for most practical purpose (this is consistence with Solovay's model).

Comment: It is perfectly possible to develop Lebesgue Integration directly, 
without developing measure theory. In this approach the results of 
measure theory are proved from the Lebesgue Integration results. 
This approach is sometimes called "Riesz approach".

Some books use such approach, although it is not the most 
common one. See, for instance, Soo Bong Chae's *Lebesgue Integration*.